# Moving OpenCart Extensions

Tags: opencart

I have an old OpenCart set up but not the extension source files.

I need to copy all OpenCart extensions from my first installation to a new one.

Both OpenCart installations have the same version. The extensions include some vQmod scripts as well.

Open Cart installation has multiple extensions installed. We have to move them to another open cart store. 
We do not have the zip files for extensions so we can not find out which files we have to move for each extension.
is there any way to identify the files for each extension or download them from the first opencart setup ?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? Is *COPY + PASTE* not working for you?

Comment: enhance your description and clearify what you want to know

Comment: @shadyyx, COPY + PASTE would work fine if we can identify the files for each extensions.

Comment: @niyou, I have tried to explain in more detail.

Comment: I have modified your question and changed all *open cart* to *OpenCart* and yet you again put in some *open cart* - what is *open cart* supposed to be? To answer your question - no, there is no way how to determine which files are required for what extension. You can just compare the *clean* installation against the old one and copy/move all the different files...If you would like to copy/move only some extensions, then this gets even harder...

Comment: which openCart version you are using???

Answer (score 0):

admin(remove config.php)
catalog
download
image
system
vqmod
index.php

copy all files to your new opencart excpet the config.php and admin/config.php

Answer (score 0):

which openCart version you are using???
Actually there is no way to find it automatically But there is a way manually but it took too much time

- compare your exiting opencart version  files with same version default opencart files(Remaining Files are your Extension Files )[Here you can find defaul OpenCart versions Files, Download and compare with your relevant version](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=cms/download/history)
- Secondly go into Admin side there in modification there you will find modification log there you can find where and to which files to some specify extent-on are effected For Example
  `----------------------------------------------------------------
  MOD: NitroPack

FILE: system/library/db.php
CODE: if (class_exists($class)) {
LINE: 37

FILE: system/engine/front.php
CODE: require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'journal2/startup.php');
LINE: 52

FILE: system/engine/router.php
CODE: require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'journal2/startup.php');
LINE: 52

FILE: system/library/image.php
CODE: public function save($file, $quality = 90) {
LINE: 117
CODE: if ($width_orig != $width || $height_orig != $height) {
LINE: 34
CODE: if ($width_orig != $width || $height_orig != $height) {
LINE: 34

FILE: system/library/document.php
CODE: return $this->styles;
LINE: 125
CODE: return $this->scripts[$postion];
LINE: 153
----------------------------------------------------------------`
This is the log  for my installed Extension (module NitroPAck) here you can see that every trace and modification is described